# Deploy spring boot microservices to heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to deploy my microservices to heroku but without success. At first I created application for service registry (eureka) with following configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka

server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

Next I deploy application, url of deployed app is like https://eureka.herokuapp.com. I configure with this url my other apps like gateway and business services.

Example of my gateway configuration

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
server:
  port: 8081

eureka:
  client:
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://eureka.herokuapp.com/eureka/
```

same configuration I used for my user service, just different app name (user-service). When I go to `https://gateway.herokuapp.com/user-service/user` I cannot receive any response. In heroku logs of gateway app I can see exception because of timeout of user service which I don't understand because when I call `https://user.herokuapp.com/user` directly I get response

I also find out in my eureka dashboard is not registered replicas, I am not sure if it ok. Can you tell me what I did wrong? Thank you.

[image]

error log from gateway app:

> 2019-12-01T19:53:29.503419+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/user-service/user" host=gateway.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=7818f5eb-34af-47f9-94db-7dc4f9609c31 fwd="86.49.253.78"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8110ms status=500 bytes=465
>   protocol=https

Answer (score 1):

Your gateway configuration missing gateway discovery section. Also registry does not require "serviceUrl"

Try bellow configuration

### registry

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka

server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: false
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

### Gateway

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    discovery:
      enabled: true 
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true

server:
  port: 8081

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://eureka.herokuapp.com/eureka/
```